# How can I know why my app is crashing in some devices

Tags: android

My app is running fine in the emulator, and at Nokia 6 plus mobile, but it is crashing while running at Motorola motoOne, how can I find the reason of this?

Comment: try implementing `Firebase Crashlytics` https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics.

have a look at this for a complete guide on how to implement it : https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Yeah, use Firebase Crashlytics or firebase also has test lab where you can run your app on up to 5 physical and 10 virtual devices per day for free and it gives you all the information you need